# Optimize Joins with CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a query, Please help me with Possible ways I can Optimize my Query.
I have used two CTE and then applied JOIN.The first CTE provide Data for year 2018 and second CTE provide data for year 2019. Two join data of both the years on Country i applied Join.

Query

```
    with cte as
    (
     select aa.Country_Name, SUM(MQTY) Qty from(
     select * from ExportData where YEAR in ('0119','0219','0319') and FINANCIAL_YEAR='2018-19'
    union
    select * from ExportData where YEAR not in ('0120','0220','0320') and FINANCIAL_YEAR='2019-20'
    )ab inner join countrymaster aa on COD=Country_Code
     where DCODE in ('0502','0503','0504','0505','0506','0507','0508')
     group by aa.Country_Name
    )
     ,cte1 as
    (
    select aa.Country_Name, SUM(MQTY) Qty from (
    select * from ExportData where YEAR in ('0118','0218','0318') and FINANCIAL_YEAR='2017-18'
    union
    select * from ExportData where YEAR not in ('0119','0219','0319') and FINANCIAL_YEAR='2018-19'
    )ab inner join countrymaster aa on COD=Country_Code
     where DCODE in ('0502','0503','0504','0505','0506','0507','0508')
     group by DGCTRCOD,aa.Country_Name
     ) 
     select cte.Country_Name, cte1.Qty 'Qty 2018', cte.Qty 'QTY 2019' from cte 
     inner join cte1 on cte.Country_Name = cte1.Country_Name
```

Required Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: There's quite a lot that can/could be done. But it depends on your underlying database and tables. I.e. indexation, are indexes present, are they being used. How big are your tables? If you want performance tuning, what is your bottleneck? You should get the execution plan and post it using: [PasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) so people can actually see what your DBMS is doing with this query.

Comment: `group by DGCTRCOD,aa.Country_Name` (in cte1) looks suspect. Why is it different from the first cte? Why not group by `country_name` first?

Comment: `UNION` will look for duplicate rows, and then 'distinct' them if found, which takes time. The `WHERE` conditions on each side suggest that `UNION ALL` would give the exact same results, without all that checking. Even better, you can probably remove the `UNION (ALL)` and combine the conditions with an `(...) OR (...)` in the single `WHERE` that remains.

Comment: @joop Corrected CTE1

Comment: @PurnimaBhatia . . . You should provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Comment: @GordonLinoff here is my output, I am getting the result, but i want if i can optimize my query or any other better way

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you required UNION or CTE. you can get desire results by using OR condition in where clause like below

```
  select aa.Country_Name, SUM(MQTY) Qty 
  from(
          select * 
          from ExportData 
          where ( YEAR in ('0119','0219','0319') and FINANCIAL_YEAR='2018-19' ) OR
                ( YEAR not in ('0120','0220','0320') and FINANCIAL_YEAR='2019-20') OR
                ( YEAR in ('0118','0218','0318') and FINANCIAL_YEAR='2017-18') OR
                ( YEAR not in ('0119','0219','0319') and FINANCIAL_YEAR='2018-19')

   )ab 
   inner join countrymaster aa on COD=Country_Code
   where DCODE in ('0502','0503','0504','0505','0506','0507','0508')
   group by aa.Country_Name
```

Comment: You didn't understand my Point... Check the the last line where am applying join between both CTE

Answer (score 0):

Temporary tables could be used instead of Cte, it should improve performance

```
Create table #T
  ( Country_Name varchar(max),
    Qty INT
  )

 Create table #T1
  ( Country_Name varchar(max),
    Qty INT
  )


INSERT INTO #T
          select aa.Country_Name, SUM(MQTY) Qty 
          from(
                  select * 
                  from ExportData 
                  where YEAR in ('0119','0219','0319') and 
                        FINANCIAL_YEAR='2018-19'
                  union
                  select * 
                  from ExportData 
                  where YEAR not in ('0120','0220','0320') and
                  FINANCIAL_YEAR='2019-20'
           )ab 
           inner join countrymaster aa on COD=Country_Code
           where DCODE in ('0502','0503','0504','0505','0506','0507','0508')
           group by aa.Country_Name


 INSERT INTO #T1
           select aa.Country_Name, SUM(MQTY) Qty 
           from (
                   select * 
                   from ExportData  
                   where YEAR in ('0118','0218','0318') and 
                         FINANCIAL_YEAR='2017-18'
                   union
                   select * 
                   from ExportData 
                   where YEAR not in ('0119','0219','0319') and 
                         FINANCIAL_YEAR='2018-19'
                )ab 
                inner join countrymaster aa on COD=Country_Code
                where DCODE in ('0502','0503','0504','0505','0506','0507','0508')
                group by aa.Country_Name


SELECT  cte.Country_Name, cte1.Qty 'Qty 2018', cte.Qty 'QTY 2019' 
FROM #T 
     INNER JOIN #T1 on T.Country_Name = T1.Country_Name
```

Answer (score -1):

You can start by avoiding the (select *) and select just the columns you need.

Comment: this answer would have been better as just a comment.  You supply no real answer here.